# Filtering by multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create multiple choice filter. So there should be a div with content and other div's that u can click and toggle. For test purposes I just created something like that: [jsfiddle my code](http://jsfiddle.net/eXhqu/)

That is pretty what I want so going on - I can't write the same functionality but for toggling buttons (tw bootstrap) or other divs. I don't know how to modify that part `$.map($(':checked')` to properly create my chain of id's.

When I used tw bootstrap buttons I just tried to write something like: `$.map($('.active')` but it didn't work. So how to do to create that functionality but for that case with buttons from tw bootstrap?

**Little edit:** And how to do this using div's like buttons? I mean there will be some div's and jQuery creating class "active".

checkboxes with have that code: http://jsfiddle.net/eXhqu/

Comment: Exactly what kind of toggleable buttons in Bootstrap are you talking about? I don't see any “toggle buttons” in [Bootstrap’s component list](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).

Comment: I want to use this one: <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="feature1" onclick="filter()" >feature1</button></div>

Comment: [buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/eFswC/) - this is code of my checkbox buttons from twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine, except that `filter()` function is fired before bootstrap function. You can use setTimeout with 1ms delay.

Look at my version of code: http://jsfiddle.net/eFswC/1/